# "I told you how I felt that nothing could come close." or "I told you how I felt that nothing comes close."

Tags: difference, past-tense

I'm confused about this since this is in past tense. which one of the following is correct?

> 1 I told you how I felt that nothing could come close.

or

> 2 I told you how I felt that nothing comes close.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain the context of your sentence. If you intend 'nothing comes close' to mean 'there is nothing else that resembles [something]', you are talking about a universal truth, so the tense doesn't matter.

> I felt that it was so [then].

or

> I felt that it is so [always].

Comment: thank you for answering. my intention was to make it in past.